# Python not displaying the correct values in the HMTL table, Its displaying N/A

Tags: python, html, streamlit

Trying to figure out why its giving me an N/A in the HTML table.
Any ideas why?

Code doest show any error

```
import yfinance as yf
import streamlit as st

# Define the function to fetch stock data from Yahoo Finance API
def fetch_stock_data(ticker):
    # Get the stock price
    try:
        price = yf.Ticker(ticker).info["price"]
    except KeyError:
        price = None

    # Get the dividend yield
    try:
        dividend_yield = yf.Ticker(ticker).info["dividendYield"]
    except KeyError:
        dividend_yield = 0

    return price, dividend_yield

# Define the function to update the stock data
def update_stock_data():
    # Define the S&P 500 and Nasdaq ticker symbols
    sp500_tickers = ["AAPL", "MSFT", "AMZN", "GOOGL", "BRK.A", "JPM", "V", "UNH", "TSLA"]
    nasdaq_tickers = ["AMZN", "MSFT", "GOOGL", "AAPL", "NVDA", "TSLA", "BABA", "AMZN", "INTC"]

    # Get the latest stock data for the S&P 500 and Nasdaq ticker symbols
    sp500_data = [fetch_stock_data(ticker) for ticker in sp500_tickers]
    nasdaq_data = [fetch_stock_data(ticker) for ticker in nasdaq_tickers]

    # Sort the stock data by dividends payment
    sp500_data = sort_stock_data(sp500_data)
    nasdaq_data = sort_stock_data(nasdaq_data)

    # Update the stock data in the web app
    st.write("**S&P 500**")
    st.table(sp500_data)
    st.write("**Nasdaq**")
    st.table(nasdaq_data)

# Define the function to sort the stock data by dividends payment
def sort_stock_data(data):
    return sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

# Define the main function
def main():
    # Update the stock data every 24 hours
    update_stock_data()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The image show that the HTML values are empty, N/A

Image
[image]

Get HTML values in the table
[image]

Comment: Did you verify in your code that the values there are not `N/A` already?

Comment: @t.niese I dont see that in the code. can you point me where the "N/A" can be?